# what are 2D point groups with respect to a 2D lattice

Tags: solid-state-physics

I am having trouble understand how you calculate the point group of a 2d lattice, I am currently reading 'Solid state physics' by J.R.Hook and H.E.Hall and the book talk briefly about point groups and rotation of axis ect, but it just not clicking for what point groups are, and why they used.

So for example take a square 2d lattice, if I have understand correctly is transitional invariance and if you place a rotation axis on each point then it would have a 4 fold rotation so a 4 point group, but dose this mean that a hexagon is a 6 point group, as this would also have transitional invariance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you have to distinguish the translational symmetry of a crystal from its point symmetries, they are different things.

The point symmetry group of a crystal is usually not 'calculated', but it can be determined by inspection. Doing that means essentially trying out if the crystal is mapped onto itself by elementary point symmetry operations. These are

- n-fold rotations (rotations about an axis by 360deg/n, n=1,2,3,4,6)
- inversion at a point
- reflection at mirror planes
- n-fold rotation about an axis, followed by reflection at a plane normal to this axis
- identity

Once you found a collection of symmetry operations for your crystal, you can check that pairwise combinations of them are also symmetry operations of your crystal. Eventually you end up with a finite set of symmetry operations, which forms a mathematical group.
All point groups of crystals have a finite number of elements. Furthermore, there is a finite number of crystal point groups in 2D (10) and 3D (32). They are all known and tabulated (see, e.g., [Point group-Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_group))

In case of your example, the 2D square lattice in the $x$-$y$ plane: it has a 4-fold rotation symmetry ($C_4$) about an axis in $z$-direction, as you mentioned, but it also has a 2-fold rotation symmetry ($C_2$) about the same axis. In addition, it has mirror symmetries (there are mirror planes along the sides of the squares, but also mirror planes along the diagonals of the squares), which you may also see as two-fold rotations about axes in the $x$-$y$ plane. In total, there are therefore 8 distinct symmetry operations that map the square lattice onto itself:

1. Identity
2. Two four-fold rotations about $z$
3. A two-fold rotation about $z$
4. Two two-fold rotations about $x$ and $y$ (sides of the squares are oriented along $x$ and $y$)
5. Two two-fold rotations about axes along the two diagonals of the square

These eight symmetry operations form a group called the *dihedral group* $D_4$.